# MarkLogic 8 and server-side JavaScript - XPath Queries on Sequences

Tags: javascript, xpath, xquery, marklogic

In XQuery, you can very efficiently execute an XPath query on an API function which returns a sequence:

```
fn:collection("abstract")//author
```

With [server-side JavaScript](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/jsref), this doesn't seem to be possible. You can iterate the sequence in a loop, and execute an XPath query on the individual documents, but it can't be very efficient:

```
var authors = [];
for ( var doc of fn.collection("abstract")){
  authors.push( doc.xpath("//author") );
}
```

Is there any plan to provide this facility, or a workaround to allow it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Certainly we hope to improve the Javascript APIs as we go, but in general Javascript works better with JSON and XQuery works better with XML: not surprising, as the languages were each designed with those data formats in mind.

For the particular case in mind, you can also use the DOM APIs: `doc.getElementsByTagName("author")`. It will have a little less overhead than the xpath call. The other thing to know is that you can give a full XPath as the argument to xpath, e.g.

```
anydoc.xpath("collection('abstract')//author")
```

This will give you all the articles in 'abstract', regardless of what document they are in.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the toArray() function to get an array from a ValueIterator, as in:

```
fn.collection("abstract").toArray();
```

For more, see:

http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/jsref/api#id_90070

Hoping that helps,